# "Unable to enumerate USB device" and definitely not a typewriter, installing Elementary OS on a 2019 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook, install

Assuming this hasn't been asked a hundred times, I am installing on a late-2019 13" MacBook Pro ***/wo*** Touch Bar or Touch ID. I am able to install Parrot OS, so this should be cake. It isn't.

The initial screen comes up, asking whether I want to try or install Elementary OS, fine. When I hit return, the screen flashes some ASPCI errors in various font sizes (drivers kicking in?). It then gives a series of IO errors:

Something like...

Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: Maybe there's something wrong with the USB cable?
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: Maybe there's something wrong with the USB cable?
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: Unable to enumerate USB device
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
Stdin: This is not a typewriter
...

Basically for infinity.

The "USB device" is a USB 3.2 2nd Gen 32Gig thumb drive that I just opened. And it works for all other purposes.

What am I doing wrong (or almost right)?

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but for solidarity - I have a very similar problem installing Elementary OS on a 2017 Macbook Pro.
Getting a seemingly endless stream of

```
stdin: Invalid argument
stdin: Not a typewriter
```

After pressing return a few dozen times it gets to

```
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
```

Then it goes through some unsuccessful attempts to netboot and drops to initramfs shell (it's a bit tricky though, since whatever commands you type appear somewhere below the edge of screen and only become visible after spamming return many times).

Theoretically it should be possible to troubleshoot/boot Linux via initramfs, but I don't know how to do that. I also tried booting manually from the grub command line (following instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot)) but that just dropped me back to the elementary installation menu.

My working hypothesis is that it happens because Mac has problems reading the USB drive properly, so I'm looking into options to install Linux on a disk partition without employing USB.

Meanwhile, if you had any breakthroughs in your struggle, I'd be delighted to hear about them.